# Starting Konsole on a display and with a specified command from SSH?

Tags: kde, konsole

If I have $DISPLAY set to a particular display and I'm connected through SSH, can I make a Konsole window appear on display $DISPLAY and run a bash command from it right away?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/581922/export-display-value-in-shell-script